# Getting Ajax response (JSON) to PHP Variable

Tags: php, ajax, json

From my form I can successfully send the correct data and receive the correct response, however I am stuck on how I decode the response to a PHP variable so I can manipulate and store it in a session.

I receive my reply like so:

```
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        console.log(response);
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
```

and my responses will be one of the below:

```
error: 1
error_msg: "Incorrect"
success: 0
tag: "login"

error: 0
success: 1
tag: "login"
user: Object
profileimageurl: "test"
uid: "1"
userEmail: "email@domain.com"
userFirstName: "Test"
userLastName: "User"
```

How would I get the error message of it fails and the userid if successful?

Edit: Added Request Code

```
$('#loginSubmit').click(function () {
    //start the ajax

        var f = $("#loginForm");

            request = $.ajax({
                //this is the php file that processes the data 
                url: "app/index.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: f.serialize(),
                dataType:"json",
                cache: false
                  });
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

        console.log(response);
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
         alert("fail")
    });
```

I have tried $json_decode(response) but this is not defined? Pretty sure I cant use plain old PHP in the javascript? What I basically want is:

```
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

            myphpvar = response[user][id]
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code where you are sending to PHP.

Comment: In short, in the PHP POST handler that receives the data, you'd need to do something like: $_SESSION["foo"] = json_decode($_POST["form_data"])

Comment: use json.stringify(yourdata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try decode it using parseJSON() function, like the following:

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
alert( obj.uid );

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: Could you please copy the response from browser console, so we insure the returned data is right formatted?

Comment: That is the response :-)

Comment: Hence the JSON is not right formatted. Take a look into an example from jQuery website, it might be helpful: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: JSON was correctly formatted, turns out removing this call fixes it dataType:"json", thanks for having a go :-)